# Sorting LinkedList with even after odd elements

Tags: java, algorithm, mergesort

I am trying to solve this question : "Arrange elements in a given Linked List such that, all even numbers are placed after odd numbers. Respective order of elements should remain same."

This is the code I am using :

```
class Node<T> {
    T data;
    Node<T> next;
    Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

This is the main logic :

```
static Node<Integer> sortOddEven(Node<Integer> head) {
    if(head == null || head.next == null) {
        return head;
    }

    Node<Integer> middle = getMiddle(head);
    Node<Integer> nextOfMiddle = middle.next;

    middle.next = null;

    Node<Integer> temp1 = sortOddEven(head);
    Node<Integer> temp2 = sortOddEven(nextOfMiddle);

    Node<Integer> sortedList = sortOddEvenMerger(temp1, temp2);
    return sortedList;
}

static Node<Integer> sortOddEvenMerger(Node<Integer> head1, Node<Integer> head2) {
    Node<Integer> head3 = null, tail3 = null;

    if(head1.data.intValue()%2 != 0) {
        head3 = head1;
        tail3 = head1;

        head1 = head1.next;
    } else {
        head3 = head2;
        tail3 = head2;

        head2 = head2.next;
    }

    while(head1 != null || head2 != null) {

        if(head1 == null) {
            tail3.next = head2;

            return head3;
        } else if(head2 == null){
            tail3.next = head1;

            return head3;
        }

        if(head1.data.intValue()%2 != 0) {
            tail3.next = head1;
            tail3 = tail3.next;

            head1 = head1.next;
        } else {
            tail3.next = head2;
            tail3 = tail3.next;

            head2 = head2.next;
        }

    }

    tail3.next = null;

    return head3;
}
```

Basically I have tweaked `MergeSort` algorithm a little bit to solve this one, if I encounter odd elements , I add them first in the `sortOddEvenMerger` method and even elements after them. But the relative order of elements get changed.

> Example : Input - 1 4 5 2
>
> Expected output - 1 5 4 2
>
> My output - 1 5 2 4

How can I tweak it more to maintain the relative order?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your approach is not only making the problem more difficult than it is but is also more inefficient since if I'm understanding it correctly it is `O(nlgon)`. This is because you're trying to implement mergesort algorithm and you sort the odd (and even)-elements which leads to wrong results.

A simple algorithm:

- Make two new lists (one for odd one for even elements) which are initially empty.
- Traverse the main list and add every odd element you find in odd list and every even element in even list. This is `O(n)` for traversal and `O(1)` for each insertion in each lists.
- When no elements are left in main list you have two lists odd-even with elements having right order so just link them to get one list with expected output- this step is `O(1)` as well!

**Total complexity: O(n).** (where n the length of main list).

Comment: Surely the last step is `O(1)` if you maintain a reference to the last `Node` in the odd list and the head of the even list? `oddCurrent.next = evenHead` (of course checks should be added to ensure `oddCurrent != null`, which is possible). I guess judging by what you said `O(n)` was a typo.

Comment: Thanks fro comment!!! Actually I didn't to think at all since an O(n) at last step would not change the overall complexity but yes you're totally right !! (I'll edit the answer thanks again!!).

Comment: in terms of big O no, but in practice yes. I'll delete my comment in a moment to keep the answer tidy, which was otherwise spot on.

Comment: Totally agree, but I think this is a very useful comment it may be better to exist...

Comment: Since we're leaving the comments, I should say that `oddTail` would be a better name than `oddCurrent`, but I can no longer edit.

Comment: I agree this may make it more understandable :) !!

Answer (score 0):

Python code for this problem:

```py
def evenAfterOdd(head):
    if head is None:
        return head
    end = head
    prev = None
    curr = head

    # Get pointer to last Node
    while (end.next != None):
        end = end.next

    new_end = end

    # Consider all even nodes before getting first odd node
    while (curr.data % 2 != 1 and curr != end):
        new_end.next = curr
        curr = curr.next
        new_end.next.next = None
        new_end = new_end.next

    # do following steps only if there is an odd node
    if (curr.data % 2 == 1):

        head = curr

        # now curr points to first odd node
        while (curr != end):

            if (curr.data % 2 == 1):

                prev = curr
                curr = curr.next

            else:

                # Break the link between prev and curr
                prev.next = curr.next

                # Make next of curr as None
                curr.next = None

                # Move curr to odd
                new_end.next = curr

                # Make curr as new odd of list
                new_end = curr

                # Update curr pointer
                curr = prev.next

    # We have to set prev before executing rest of this code
    else:
        prev = curr

    if (new_end != end and end.data % 2 != 1):
        prev.next = end.next
        end.next = None
        new_end.next = end
    return head
```

Comment: Code only answers are discouraged. Please provide a summary of how your answer solves the problem and why it may be preferable to the other answers already provided.